# Dialogflow Console doesn't show Facebook Messenger option for responding

Tags: dialogflow-es

[Here's what I mean. The only response from Dialogflow is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsSj6.png)

I have integrated facebook messenger, and it works fine when testing with the messenger. I want to access the JSON data that Dialogflow console provides when I'm interacting with messenger.

Answer (score 0):

It will only show up, if you have added something explicitly for facebook in the facebook response tab or the webhook response.

[image: facebook response tab]

---

You can however find the JSON data from your facebook interactions in the history. Click on the three dots next to a response and click *raw interaction log*

Comment: I added a response in the facebook tab, but I cannot see an option for the messenger.

Comment: @YankeeMaharjan What do you mean with "messenger" I assumed you meant the "Facebook Messenger"?